# Rails route architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, routes

I'm trying to understand the best way to architect a fairly simple relationship. I have a Job Model and a Category Model with a has_many relationship between them in a JobCategories model.

I'd like to have a page that lists all Jobs for a specific Category.  Should the logic to pull this data be on the Category Controller (on the show action), or should I create a category method on the Job Controller?  My gut tells me it should be on the Category side because a Category has Jobs, but it doesn't feel right that a Job would have the logic to pull all the Jobs for a given category.

Having said that, if I want the URL to be something that is more Job specific like:

```
domain/jobs/:id/{category-name} (for SEO purposes)
```

How would I structure the route so that it reads like the above, as opposed to

```
domain/categories/:id
```

which is what you'd get with `resources :categories, only: [:show]`

Thanks!

Comment: it really should be on the Category side.  Since you want all jobs that have that category.  IF on the job side, you need to know the Job before you can find out the category

Comment: Thanks - any thoughts on how to structure the route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a pretty slug, I'd suggest using [FriendlyId](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) on your categories model.

As for the routes, you will not get the desired route using `resources :categories`

One way to do it would be

```
resources :jobs, only: [] do
  member do
    get '/:slug' => 'categories#some_action'
  end
end
```

the slug will be passed in your parameters.

This will yield a route like this

```
GET    /jobs/:id/:slug(.:format)    categories#some_action
```

**UPDATE**

the `:slug` is just an example for pretty url.

In your case you'd want to have `:category_name`. That would be passed into your controller through the `params[:category_name]`.

One thing that I did start thinking when I re-read your question is that you want to show a list of jobs for a specific category. A url path like `/jobs/:id/{category-name}` shouldn't actually show a list of jobs as you are specifying an `id` which means a specific job. I think the url that you're looking to get is more along the lines of `/jobs/{category-name}`. Am I correct?

**UPDATE 2**

I suggest you read this [Ruby On Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-names)

**UPDATE 3**

Since you did want an url more like `/jobs/{category-name}`

You're routes should look like this

```
resources :jobs, only: [] do
  collection do
    get '/:category_name' => 'categories#some_action'
  end
end
```

Good luck with your project! :D

Comment: Thanks - where does `/collaborators/` come from in your example?

Comment: Whoops that was my bad...I used it in one of my applications as an example and forgot to edit that out

Comment: Thx.  Should I literally be using `:/slug` in the route?  If I do that I get no _path or url_ shortcut when running rake routes.

Comment: I added an update on my answer. Also, what do you mean a path or url shorcut? If you wanted to add name to the route you'd have to use the `:as` option..

Comment: "I think the url that you're looking to get is more along the lines of /jobs/{category-name}"  Yes.